# Regular expression with cucumber doesn't match the string

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, cucumber, gherkin

I'm writing in Java and using cucumber with Eclipse to search for specific words. The requirements are as below:

> // Pattern distinguished.
> // Should match the string starting with:test_splitter arg
> // Where  should match the following positive examples
> // and not negative examples.  Note: any string not in the
> // positive or negative examples can be accepted or rejected.

The positive words are (spill, Sponge, tap, rebuild) and negative ones are (si, egregious, Foul, Test, top, ta)

by writing the regular expression in the Stepdefs.java file, this is what I wrote

```
@When("^test_splitter (?=.*?\bspill\b)(?=.*?\bSponge\b)(?=.*?\btap\b)(?=.*?\brebuilld\b)((?!si|egregious|Foul|Test|ta).)*$")
public void test_splitter(String match) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("test_splitter true for: " + match);
}
```

now when I write tests (in Gherkin language) for this method in the Test.feature file the tests fail, which should all pass )

```
Scenario: test regular expressions that should pass
  When test_splitter spill
  When test_splitter Sponge
  When test_splitter tap
  When test_splitter rebuild
  When test_splitter2 spill
  When test_splitter2 Sponge
  When test_splitter2 tap
  When test_splitter2 rebuild
```

What is the problem with my regex? How can I write the regex in a better way?

Comment: I am not sure what should be the purpose of your regexp. It looks really messy but as far as I can see you are using several lookaheads which means all they should match at the same time. So if you say have `spill` but don't have `Sponges`  your line wont match.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am fairly new to regexp and still struggling. I have edited now like this `"^test_splitter2 (?=.*?\bspill|Sponge|tap|rebuild\b)((?!si|egregious|Foul|Test|ta).)*$"` but it's failing in the Gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

i think the test_splitter tap and test_splitter2 tap are failing. At the end of your regular expression change "ta" to "top". Then all your tests should pass and failed scenarios will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up